# Make entire div a link

Tags: html

How would I go about making this div a link to a page?  There are some links within the div, which I am wondering, does that prevent me from making the entire div a link? as you can see I have tried wrapping the div in a a tag, but that does not work. I got it to work with javascript, but the 'hand' pointer doesn't show up when hovering over the div. I know I could add this in CSS, but I would prefer to do it with link tags.

```
<a style="display:block" href="viewmessagethread.php?id=<?php echo $messageid; ?>">
    <div class="<?php echo $message_read_status; ?>">
            <div class="media-body">
                <span class="pull-right noti-time"> <?php echo $dte_new; ?></span>
                <div width="100%"><b><?php echo $title;?></b>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if there are links within the `<div>`, that won’t work. An `<a>` element automatically ends at the start of another “nested” `<a>` element. Just like with `<p>`.

See the [MDN docs on `<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> Permitted content: flow content (**excluding interactive content**) or phrasing content.

> Permitted parents: Any element that accepts phrasing content, or any element that accepts flow content, **but always excluding `<a>` elements** (according to the logical principle of symmetry, if `<a>` tag, as a parent, can not have interactive content, then the same `<a>` content can not have `<a>` tag as its parent).

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I guess I'll stick with javascript.